# How to create Ubuntu LiveUSB manually

Tags: grub2, live-usb, persistence

The thing I'm trying to do:

1. Make a bootable USB with two partitions (bootable FAT32 and NTFS for data). (DONE)
2. Install GRUB2 to FAT32 partition. (DONE)
3. Make FAT32 partition multiboot, with persistent installed Ubuntus.

The last one shouldn't be that hard, but now my head is about to blow... I can't find anywhere step-by-step instructions on how to do persistent installation of Ubuntu on one partition and not in the root directory (in ubuntu12.04 folder for example). At this time I've gathered information from it looks like all internet and here what I've done:

1. Extracted Ubuntu 12.04 LiveCD ISO into `/ubuntu12.04` directory.
2. Created `/ubuntu12.04/casper-rw` file using `dd` and `mkfs.ext2` it.
3. Added `menuentry` to `grub.cfg`:

   ```
   menuentry "Run Ubuntu 12.04.2 Live" {
       linux   /ubuntu12.04/casper/vmlinuz  file=/ubuntu12.04/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper persistent rw quiet splash --
       initrd  /ubuntu12.04/casper/initrd.lz
   }
   ```

But result are always the same:

```
(initramfs): Unable to find a medium containing a live file system.
```

Where should I place `casper-rw` file to make initramfs find it?
Or anything to get what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Ubuntu 12.04.2, the kernel is `/casper/vmlinuz.efi`. Notice the `.efi` was added in recently.

Also, you don't need to extract the CD files, you can boot directly from the `.iso`. Here's a template I use for USB multiboot:

```
menuentry "YOUR TITLE" {
    insmod ntfs
    insmod iso9660
    loopback loop /distros/FILENAME.ISO
    linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz.efi persistent boot=casper iso-scan/filename="/distros/FILENAME.ISO" noeject noprompt splash toram --
    initrd (loop)/casper/initrd.lz
}
```

This way I can keep all distros/versions as their pristine .iso files in a `/distros` directory inside the NTFS data partition. Grub2 is installed to the MBR, and its `/boot` files (including the above handwritten `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`) also in the data partition. Grub2 was installed as:

```
sudo grub-install --no-floppy --root-directory="/PATH/TO/MOUNTED/USB" "/dev/sdX"
```

Comment: This way doesn't looks like persistent... does it save changes after reboot?

Comment: @MadBrozzeR: just add `persistent` to the `linux` line and create the `mkfs.ext2`'ed `casper-rw` file in the root of partition.

Comment: Also after learning initrd.lz archive I found `persistet-path` parameter, and now I don't have to keep `casper-rw` in partition root (to have separate filesystems for each distro... don't sure though I really need it).

Comment: @MadBrozzeR: glad it worked! 3 things to note: It's `persistent-path`; it may not work if the USB filesystem it resides is NTFS (but worth trying); and the casper file filesystem does not need to be `ext2`, it can also be `ext3` or `ext4` (recommended)

Answer (score 0):

Manual creation of the boot disk using grub is pretty fragile from my experience. If it is made on a efi system it will not work on bios systems, failing  with the error

```
error:invalid arch independent ELF magic.
grub rescue>
```

On efi only systems, bios bootoaders *may* not work. Best is to go for both grub-efi and syslinux just like the automaticaly created live CD.

You might want to do this to

a) prevent a bazilion folders and files from cluttering your pendrive and rendering it unusable for any other purpose

b)multibooting

---

The technique I use is as follows: put grub:

```
sudo grub-install --removable --root-directory=/path/to/mount /dev/sdx
```

the `--removable` seems to be needed or it produces funny install errors on some computers with efi

```
Fatal: Couldn't open either sysfs or procfs directories for accessing EFI variables.
Try 'modprobe efivars' as root.
```

this creates a `boot` and an `efi` folder. to install syslinux inside the `boot` folder (unlike the standard live cd):

```
cd /path/to/mount
sudo syslinux --directory boot/syslinux --install /dev/sdx
```

extract the ubuntu iso to a folder say ubuntu (`/path/to/mount/ubuntu`)
edit `/path/to/mount/boot/grub/grub.cfg` to contain:

```
menuentry "Ubuntu" {
    set gfxpayload=keep
    linux   /ubuntu/casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash live-media-path=/ubuntu/casper --
    initrd  /ubuntu/casper/initrd.lz
}
```

then set up the syslinux:
copy `vesamenu.c32` from the isolinux directory in the iso to `/path/to/mount/boot/syslinux/vesamenu.c32`
create `/path/to/mount/boot/syslinux/slax.cfg` to contain:

```
PROMPT 0
TIMEOUT 90
DEFAULT /boot/syslinux/vesamenu.c32


LABEL Ubuntu
MENU LABEL Ubuntu
    kernel  /ubuntu/casper/vmlinuz.efi  
    append initrd=/ubuntu/casper/initrd.lz boot=casper live-media-path=/ubuntu/casper quiet splash --
```